# 1972 international Harvester Scout II 345 engine - LOUD bang & PLUMES white smoke from engine

Tags: engine, carburetor

Just put water in radiator, heard and felt VERY LOUD BANG from engine and massive amounts of white smoke blew from engine when trying to start.  Engine didn't turnover & turned off key ASAP. Waited 1/2 hr and truck started but saw carb loading up and shut if off. Recently carb has been flooding out. Read Question 7 however was more than just strange engine noise - blew valve cover gasket out. Diagnosis anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds as though you have a head gasket leak. Might have even hydrolocked (bang), then started trying to run with large amounts of white exhaust. If so, not a good situation.